# making an element fill available space provided by parent container

Tags: css

I have a fluid article that has 2 columns 1 contains an image that fills whatever space is available for that column, the other column has text but I'm not sure how I can make this column `.content-col` occupy the space provided by `.article`. Can anyone advise how this can be achieved?

Jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/R7AuG/

**CSS Snippet**

```
.img-col{
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
}

.content-col{
    background: black;
    width: 75%;
    float: left;
}

.col{
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
```

I also understand that this could be achieved with `display:table` but I'm wondering if this can be done without?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to imitate a table, you could use a small CSS trick, namely, adding

```
overflow: hidden
```

to `article`, plus applying

```
margin-bottom:-1000em;
padding-bottom:1000em;
```

to `.content-col`

[See example](http://jsfiddle.net/2CM4f/)

Comment: nice, whats with the margin and padding calculations?

Comment: They are simply values that are supposed to ensure that the article (parent) won't be higher than div inside it (`.content-col`) Specified as 1000em so that the background will always behave as you would want it to. As far as I know, it makes no substantial performance difference, even if you set it to 5000em. I once had a case where the content exceeded 500em, but it was a really long page.